# Hardware requirements for android SDK assuming no emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an old laptop running Windows Vista with a 2.6 Ghz Intel Celeron and 2 gigs of RAM. I was considering installing Lubuntu or another lightweight Linux distro on it to use for travel. Would this be able to run the Android SDK/Eclipse reasonably well? All other threads I could find were about running the emulator-I will be running the apps on my Galaxy S4 or Nexus 7, so I just need Eclipse to run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It should be able to run it, but probably not very fast.  The Celeron line of processors had a small internal cache and were only single core.  Eclipse is a big piece of software which uses a lot of RAM and can be disk intensive as well.  I've got an older Core2 Duo 2GHz with 4GB of RAM and Eclipse/ADT can be pretty sluggish at times if I have to use that machine.  Good luck!